# FFmpeg Failed to inject frame into filter network: Out of memory

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

Recently I build ffmpeg and use it on Android device. Anything works well except such videos with metadata rotate. Here is my command:

```
[ffmpeg, -i, input.mp4, -ss, 0.0, -t, 4.748, -vcodec, libx264, -preset, ultrafast, -acodec, copy, -vf, scale=500:-2, -y, output.mp4]
```

Error log is [here](https://pastebin.com/6LgrU7ga).

In my opinion, if ffmpeg detect input video with `rotate` metadata, it will first rotate it in memory and then apply filters on the tmp videos.

I can use `noautorotate` to solve the crash. However the filter applied on the video is wrong because ffmpeg does not rotate the input video.

Can anyone explains what I guess is right or not? And if you know how to solve this crash, I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

autorotate can call upon the transpose, hflip, vflip or rotate filters, so those should be enabled, but they are missing from your build.

Edit: ffmpeg will, as of today 03-03-2019, automatically select these filters during configure.